# Angular 5 bootstrap component

Tags: angular4, angular5

Могу ли я, в конфигурации с несколькими модулями, бутстрапить, определенный компонент модуля? В основном хотелось бы это делать только в качестве шаблонизатора.
То есть, у меня есть сабмодуль admin, в котором лежит компонент admin:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AdminComponent,
        AdminPageListComponent,
        AdminPageEditComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        AdminRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthService,
        AdminService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AdminComponent],
})
export class AdminModule {
}
```

шаблон компонента, который я бы хотел загружать:

```
<div class="container">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Однако компонент не грузится.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это можно

```
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AdminModule);
```

Comment: да, это я понимаю, но мне не нужно оставить все как есть, то есть сначала грузится дефолтный app.module, а при совпадении с определенным урлом, грузится мой сабмодуль, при этом сабмодуль должен бутстрапить свой компонент

Comment: бутстрапить нужно тот модуль который является корневым, тогда у вас загрузится сабмоджуль и модуль, тот который бутстрапит платформа.

Comment: безусловно, спасибо за ответ, но у меня не работает к сожалению. Если сможете сказать, почему, буду благодарен [репа с ангуляром](https://github.com/StereoFlo/Example-Angular5/tree/master/src/app)

Comment: не грузится admin-component, в admin.module

Comment: какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: в том-то и дело, что ошибок нет, компонент просто не грузится. лог в консоль, в конструкторе компонента, ни чего не дает

Comment: а компонент и не должет грузиться, т.к. он создается из описания модуля

Comment: Так из html компонента я тоже ни чего не вижу. было бы здорово сделать <div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>, тем самым обернуть другие компоненты в собственный шаблон

Comment: не могу представить себе компоненты у которых нет шаблона, а для использования роутера нужно писать отдельный модуль.